# created_by not working with ManyToManyField django

Tags: python, django, manytomanyfield

Hello everyone I'm trying top build a task manager web app using django, I need to assign task to one or multiple users I'm using manytomany relation in `models.py` and in `views.py` I'm adding `created_by` user automatically.

My problem is that when I do that I see that no users selected in assigned users but if I add created by user from the form it worked well.

```
class Task(models.Model):
    task_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    shortcode = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    task_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    task_progress = models.ForeignKey(TaskProgressStatus, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    customer_name = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    task_priority = models.ForeignKey(TaskPriority, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assigned_to_employee = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    on_account = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    currency = models.ForeignKey(Currency, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  blank=True, null=True)
    net_amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20, blank=True, null=True)
    vat = models.IntegerField(default=11)
    quote_validity = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='1 Month from offer date')
    delivered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    delivered_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    due_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='created_by_username', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file_name = models.FileField(upload_to='projects_files', null=True, blank=True)
    notes = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.task_name)


@login_required
def addtask(request):
    form = taskForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = taskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            newform = form.save(commit=False)
            newform.created_by = request.user
            newform.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)
    else:
        context = {'form':form}
        return render(request, 'tasks/add_task.html', context)
```

Comment: sorry for the the  inconsistency in my question I'm talking about the assigned_to_employee field which is ManyToManyField I already printed something and my form is valid

Comment: I can confirm that the problem only occurs when I choose assigned_to_employee = models.ManyToManyField(User) but if I change this field to ForeignKey it workes perfectly, I need to select more than one employee any suggestion to my problem is it a bug please siggest

Answer (score 0):

### Update

As well pointed out by Ahmed I. Elsayed there is some inconsistency in the title of the question, since the `created_by` field is actually a `ForeignKey`, not a `ManyToManyField`.

That being said, your issue is actually with the foreign key.

My suggestion is to first of all be sure that your form is actually valid. You can do that by printing something inside the `if form.is_valid()` block.

Comment: created_by is a FK, it's not `many`, there's no `add`

Comment: @AhmedI.Elsayed Nice catch! Updated :)